# Running a node.js process in background after giving inputs to it

Tags: linux, node.js, shell

I have this node.js server which, once spawned, expects some input from stdin. The inputs shouldn't be given straight away: I need to wait for some event before giving them (e.g. a connection from somebody). If I give the commands and close the shell, the server shuts itself down. I would like to give the input to the server and close my shell (effectively leaving the server running).

I know that to run a process in background I need to do for example `node my_server.js &`, but this prevents the input from the command line. I would like to give this input AND then put it in background. Modules like `forever` puts it in the background automatically without letting me giving the inputs through stdin.

Moreover putting the script in background kills anyways the server when closing the shell.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean that the input has to be read (from stdin)? Otherwise, there's nothing stopping you from using command line *arguments* (which would be my suggestion anyway: instead of reading the input, pass it as a command line argument to your script and either use `process.argv` or something like [optimist](https://github.com/substack/node-optimist) to read it).

Comment: Yes, I meant input read from stdin, sorry for being vague about that. I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: And using command line arguments isn't an option? An alternative could be to feed the input to the script using a file (`nohup node my_server.js < inputfile &`) or to use [forever-monitor](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor).

Comment: I took a look at forever-monitor but doesn't seem to fit. Since I have to wait for something to happen (e.g. connection from somebody) before giving inputs, giving them straight away won't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick test just using gedit in Ubuntu 12.04, and it worked.

Start your node app like so "node app.js arg1 arg2" however you want to and hit enter to start the program.  Then hit CTRL-z once your program has started running.  This gives you the terminal back but stops the process in the background.  To let it run in the background now, simply "bg" and hit enter.  This will let the process keep running now but in the background.

You can confirm you are still up with the command "ps -ef | grep node" which should show your program still running.

However, this does still leave the node process attached to the terminal window so when you close the terminal window it will close the process.  But I think this will get you most of what you seem to be looking for quick and easy.

Comment: Ctrl-Z stops (as in suspends) the process!  It does not keep running.  To get it running after Ctrl-Z you'll need to type "bg" to let it continue in the background.

Comment: Yep, only tested it halfway, didn't actually try to use it, whoops! Good catch, editing response now to add bg command afterwards

Answer (score 1):

You asked for any suggestion, so here it is: make your server able to start without user interaction.  The simplest way to do it is probably to create a file containing exactly the input needed by the server, then starting it like this:

```
node my_server.js < my_input.txt &
```

If the input needed depends on what the server outputs (ouch), use `expect(1)`.  If possible, subvert the whole thing and use a module like `commander` to get your inputs from the command line instead of stdin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I need to wait for some event before giving some of these inputs. I'll check `commander` out, even if I wanted to avoid polluting my code with other modules :-).